# Web API / Azure date changes after saved

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api2

We're developing a Single Page App using AngularJS as front end and Web API 2 back end. Data is via Entity Framework database first (EDMX) and solution is being hosted on Azure (Web App). Development is done via Visual Studio 2013 and DB is Azure SQL

I've run into something strange that I can't figure out when we are adding a number of months to an expiry date and saved in the database. This works fine when tested locally (Win 8 - IIS) but when it's published and tested to Azure the date saves fine for a moment, but then changes to double the number of months added e.g. adding 4 months to today's date would give 27/9/2015 (this is also returned correctly from the API call to the front end client), but then after a few moments it changes to 2016-01-27 in the database which is 8 months in the future

I've tried debugging it on Azure, and it appears that the correct date is set and saved (verified via SSMS) and when debugging the date doesn't change - but then when I retest after debugging the problem happens again

The code is as follows:

```
var expiryDate = new DateTime();
expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(option.FrequencyInterval);
currentPerson.MembershipExpirtyDate = expiryDate.ToUniversalTime();
db.SaveChanges();
```

Has anybody come across this before or any suggestions on what I could be missing?

Comment: What is the datatype of MembershipExpiryDate in the table?

Comment: One thing that surprised me when I set up an Azure web site (using Western European servers) was that the servers were all set to US time. This caused me some problems as I needed to know when a particular time of day in the UK was reached. If you're doing any Date processing which involves DateTime.Now or DateTime.Today it could well be using something you don't expect.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to get around it? This app needs to be used around the world so ideally

Comment: Well, you're sensibly using .ToUniversalTime(), so keep doing that with DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now. For DateTime.Today, you'll have to construct a new DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, .Month, .Day); Or you could try something to do with setting the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture which changes the timezone, but that doesn't seem too helpful in this case.

Comment: thanks @simonatrcl you pointed me in the right direction with the Datatype - changing it to datetimeoffset fixed the problem

Comment: @Mark - if DateTimeOffset fixed the problem, you should post an answer giving these details, so this question can be resolved.